# Why max() function in this following code is returning the value of C, -7 instead of -6?

Tags: python-3.x

In this code I want to find the maximum number.So,If I input (-7 -7 -7 -7 -6)
it returns me -7 instead of -6

```
A=input().split()
C=max(A)
print(C)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first line in your code, the value of A is as follows:

```
['-7', '-7', '-7', '-7', '-6']
```

When comparing strings, the comparison is lexical:

1. Is `'-'` less than `'-'`? No. Next character.
2. Is `'6'` less than `'7'`? Yes. Therefore `'-6'` is less than `'-7'`

Thus `max(A)` returns `'-7'` because the `'-6'` is less than all of the `'-7'`s.
When `print(C)` is run, the `'-7'` is printed as a string, so you don't see the quotes. If you were to `print(repr(C))` you would see `'-7'` in the output.

The fix is to convert all of the string values to integers:

```
A = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
C = max(A)
print(C)
```

Which should output `-6`.

Comment: Use `map` simply like this: `A = map(int, input().split())`

Comment: @BlackThunder `[expression for i in iterable]` is preferred (for readability) over converting a `map` to a list, but `max()` accepts an iterable so it doesn't matter either way.

Comment: Note that `max` can also accept a map object. Not everybody knows list comprehension.`map` makes it more readable near me, with the bytes decreased

Answer (score 0):

`.split()` returns a list of strings, and `list()` doesn’t change that, so `max` is giving you the maximum lexicographically:

```
>>> '-7' > '-6'
True

>>> 'cat' < 'dog'
True

>>> '2' < '10'
False
```

Convert it into a list of integers.

```
A = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
C = max(A)
print(C)
```